# AssertionConsumerService method is not hitting by itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using itfoxtec-identity-saml2 library to implement SAML2, but As per I know AssertionConsumerService method must be hit when login or logout. I have been trying all test solutions available in the github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2, but none of them hit the method. Does any one know how to force or hit this method?

I am expecting that AssertionConsumerService method be hit after login method or logout method.

Answer (score 1):

The AssertionConsumerService endpoint / method is part of the login sequence, not logout.

You can test with two [sampels](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test)

- the identity provider (IdP) [TestIdPCore](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestIdPCore)
- and the relaying party (RP) [TestWebAppCore](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCore)

You start the login sequence in the RP which call the IdP. After success or error the IdP call back the RP on the AssertionConsumerService endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Anders. In  my TestWebAppCore I set up my IdPMetadata and Issuer and it works  good. It ask me for my credential at first time and takes me back to my SP app. To test the  AssertionConsumerService I put a breakpoint, then I ran TestIdCore Project and the I ran TestWebAppCore. This one finished well but never hit the ACS. Not sure if that is the way you suggest to test it.

Comment: You need to configure Visual Studio to rune both TestIdCore and TestWebAppCore at the same time with debugger on. Then TestIdCore should hit the AssertionConsumerService endpoint after authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I already know how to hit ACS by runing TestIdCore and TestWebAppCore. In TestWebAppCore settings I left IdPMetadata pointing out to TestIdPCore and it returns AssertionConsumerService path. Briefly, TestIdPCore acts as a pivot project for others.